# Suggest an adjective for dislike of smell

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

What word can be used to describe a person who doesn't eat something because they don't like it's smell.
For example: My friend doesn't like the smell of papaya and says that he can't stand it's smell.

Comment: Do you want a word for aversion to odor or dislike of food?

Comment: It's **its**, by the way.

Comment: Example sentence please, with an X for the mystery word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For aversion to that odor - Try **osmophobic** or **olfactophobic**, an adjective from [Osmophobia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osmophobia)  defined by Wikipedia as

> Aversion or dislike to certain smells

Note that **Olfactophobia** is a synonym for Osmophobia.

For eating particular kinds of food - **oligophage** from [oligophagy](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/oligophagy#English) defined by Wikipedia as

> Feeding on certain types of food.

You can say that your friend is an oligophage or is oligophagous. 
Also, your friend is olfactophobic.